# Regular expression to test a String to contain a single forward slash and no empty spaces

Tags: java, regex

Can any one give the regular expression for checking a string

which must contain a forward slash and should not contain empty spaces.

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: well, am not good at Regular expression, but this is what i tried: ".*[/].*" this actually checks for a forward slash but will get passed if the string has more than one forward slash

Comment: Try to use this one: ^[^/\s]+/[^/\s]+$

Comment: thanks DaKirsche...its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must contain slash and must not have white space.

```
^[\S]*\/[\S]*$
```

Must contain **only one** slash and must not have white space.

```
^[^\/\s]*\/[^\/\s]*$
```

You check it at regex 101.

Comment: thanks. But how can i restrict to only one forward slash? the current expression allows more than one forward slash

Comment: You did not mention about only 1 slash.

Comment: There you go, I added the regex in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean validString(String text) {
    return (text.contains("/") && !text.contains(" "));
}
```

Comment: Question was about regex.

Comment: thanks...actually am looking for a single regex